# why do i get java.lang.StackOverflowError here?

Tags: java, exception, recursion, stack-overflow, factorial

_The following program of the below question gives series of exceptions `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at testing_package.Compute.factorial(Compute.java:105)` I don't understand why do i get this error.

**Question**: N boys and M girls are learning acting skills from a theatre. To perform a play
 they need to form a group of P actors containing not less than 4 boys and not less than 1 girl. The 
 theatre requires you to write a program that tells them the number of ways the group can be formed. 
 Note: Composition should be unique and not the order in which the composition is made of.

```
import java.io.*;

class Compute {

private static int NFact;
private static int N_Minus_R_Fact;
private static int RFact;
private static int fact=0;

public static int readTheStrengthOfGroup() {
    int strengthOfGroup=0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the strength of group : ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String read = reader.readLine();
        strengthOfGroup = Integer.parseInt(read);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
      return strengthOfGroup;
}

public static int readTheNumberOfBoys() {
   int boysToParticipate=0;
   try {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of boys to participate in the play : ");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String read = reader.readLine();
    boysToParticipate = Integer.parseInt(read);
   } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
     }
    return boysToParticipate;
}

public static int readTheNumberOfGirls() {
    int girlsToParticipate=0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of girls to participate in the play : ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String read = reader.readLine();
        girlsToParticipate = Integer.parseInt(read);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
    return girlsToParticipate;
}

public static int compute(int strengthOfGroup , int boysToParticipate , int girlsToParticipate) {
    if( boysToParticipate < 4 || girlsToParticipate < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        /*  P >= 5 
         *  N : Boys
         *  M : Girls
         *  result = M+N C P - { (N C 0)(M C P)+(N C 1)(M C P-1)+(N C 2)(M C P-2)+(N C 3)(M C P-3)+(N C P)(M C 0) }
         */
         int resultP_2 = 0;
         int totalNumberOfParticipants = boysToParticipate + girlsToParticipate;
         int totalNumberOfParticipants_C_strengthOfGroup = computeFactorial(totalNumberOfParticipants , strengthOfGroup);
         for( int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++ ) {
                          if( i == 4 ) {
                resultP_2 = resultP_2 + (computeFactorial(boysToParticipate,strengthOfGroup) * computeFactorial(girlsToParticipate,0)); 
            }else {
            resultP_2 = resultP_2 + (computeFactorial(boysToParticipate,i) * computeFactorial(girlsToParticipate,strengthOfGroup));
            strengthOfGroup--;}
         }
         int result = totalNumberOfParticipants_C_strengthOfGroup - resultP_2;
         return result;
      }
}

public static int computeFactorial(int N , int R) {
    if(R > N) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Parameters");
    } else {
        /* int NFact;
        int N_Minus_R_Fact;
        int RFact; */
        NFact = factorial(N);
        N_Minus_R_Fact = factorial(N-R);
        RFact = factorial(R);
        return( NFact / ( N_Minus_R_Fact-RFact ) );

      }
}

public static int factorial(int num) {
    if( num == 1 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        fact = num * factorial(num-1); // LINE 105
        return fact;
      }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int strengthOfGroup = readTheStrengthOfGroup();
    int boysToParticipate = readTheNumberOfBoys();
    int girlsToParticipate = readTheNumberOfGirls();
    int result = compute(strengthOfGroup , boysToParticipate , girlsToParticipate);
    System.out.println("Number of groups that can be formed : " + result);
}
```

}

I have commented line number 105.
[image]

Comment: the code you posted has 103 lines, where is the problematic line (105)?

Comment: Because you are using a recursive method. To solve it, whether improve your code or increase the stack size.

Answer (score 6):

`computeFactorial` avoids calling `factorial` if `R > N`, but calls it in all other cases (`R == N`, `R < N`), passing in `N-R`. If `R == N`, then `N-R` is `0`. In `factorial`, you're checking if `num == 1` and returning `1`, but when `num` is `0`, you're having `factorial` call itself with `num - 1`, which is `-1`. Then it calls itself again with `num - 1`, which is `-2`, and so on with with ever-increasingly-large negative numbers (`-1`, `-2`, ...) until you run out of stack.

I haven't read the code closely, but at the very least you need to have `factorial` return `1` when `num == 0` as well as when `num == 1` (`0! = 1`). I'd also have it throw an exception if you feed it a negative number.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Basically, don't pass negative numbers into `factorial`, and separately correct `factorial` so that it accepts `0` and returns the correct result (`0! = 1` just like `1! = 1`). I'd probably also have `factorial` throw an exception if you do pass it a negative number. I'm not a mathematician, but I don't think you can take the factorial of a negative number; I'm certain you can't with the usual `n! = n * (n - 1)` formula.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct - every now and then, you end up calling factorial( 0 ).  Since the recursion stops at 1, this is never going to be good.  If you change line 102 from `if( num == 1 ){` to `if( num == 0 ){`, your stack overflow problem will go away.  The bit about `R > N` is irrelevant - you've done this part correctly.  But you also have one more bug - the line that says `return( NFact / ( N_Minus_R_Fact-RFact ) );` should say `return( NFact / ( N_Minus_R_Fact * RFact ) );`.  Also, if you want to make the code MUCH more efficient, ... (comment continued) ...

Comment: Build up an array of factorials, starting with 0! and going up to the largest factorial that you'll need.  Don't use recursion to populate this; just do it by multiplying each result by the right number to get the next result.  Then, within the calculation, every time you need a factorial, just pull it out of the array instead of re-calculating it.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Thanks, originally I thought it was just the `0` case he'd got wrong, but then got it in my head that somehow he was also calling it (initially) with a negative number. But you're right, the guard condition `R > N` is correct. I've fixed that part of the answer.